# Crontab Change location

Tags: debian, cron

I want to set a personal crontab in another folder and executed.

For example I want it in /home/project/tasks/crontab

Like that it's easier to add/delete tasks.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cron` daemon determines where your active crontab is stored.  On my system (Ubuntu), and probably on yours, it's under `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`.

But you can maintain your crontab entries anywhere you like.  Just remember to run

```
crontab /home/project/tasks/crontab
```

every time you update it.

(I suppose you could set up a cron job to do that for you.  Disclaimer: I haven't actually tried invoking `crontab` from a cron job; I'm not 100% sure it would work.)

I personally find that a lot easier to manage than using, say, `crontab -e`; I can maintain my crontab file under a source control system, so I don't lose anything if I accidentally do `crontab -r`, for example.

**DIGRESSION :**

I suppose you could set up a cron job to do that for you.  Just as an experiment, I tried setting up a crontab with the following command:

```
* * * * *    crontab .crontab
```

After manually running `crontab .crontab` once, changes in `$HOME/.crontab` were automatically applied after I saved the file, taking effect one to two minutes later.

But personally I'd much rather just run `crontab FILENAME` manually, so I don't have to worry about what will happen if I save an intermediate version of the file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try all this. the thing is that the crontab is a shared one on SVN, and all dev doesn't have access to the server so can't launch it. In my ex company I just needed to update the crontab and it loaded everything automaticly. I'll try your methods.